# C# replace links, replace multiple line not working

Tags: c#, regex, replace, html-agility-pack

I want to go through all html links (`<a hef="" ><image/></a>`) and I want to replace them with only href values.
To do that I use HtmlAgilityPack to get all the links and then I try to replace any outer html of the link with the href.

```
result = result.Replace(l.OuterHtml, l.Text + " " + l.Href);
```

This works just fine with normal links but it is not working with long links that have images embedded in them. 
It works for `<a href="http://www.domain.net/">www.domain.Net<br /></a>`
But it does not work for

```
<a href="http://www.domain.net/property-details.aspx?state=50&amp;search=yes&amp;offset=0&amp;page=2&amp;offset=10&amp;page=3&amp;offset=20&amp;page=4&amp;offset=30&amp;page=5&amp;offset=40&amp;page=6&amp;pid=828"><image style="border: 1px solid #c99982; margin: 5px 0 0px 0;" src="http://domain.com/private/007jg5he/large_289572HESSEL_prop_photos_horse_areas_010-1" alt="Sebastopol" width="158" height="108" /></a>
```

So how do I solve this? I want to show only the Text part of the link following with the href value.

Comment: Jakupti, can you please be more specific on what you mean when you say "it does not work with long links that have images embedded in them." Specifically, what is the result you're seeing?

Comment: It just does not do the replacement at all it shows the same content as the original even after the replace.
result = preresult.Replace(l.OuterHtml, l.Text + " " + l.Href);
preresult = result so no replacement is done even though I could see that the OuterHtml past exist on the text

Answer (score 0):

You don't need (nor should you use) regular expressions here.  That's the whole point of using the parser in the first place.

```
HtmlDocument doc = ...;
var query = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("a");
foreach (var a in query.ToArray())
{
    a.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(HtmlNode.CreateNode(a.Attributes["href"].Value), a);
}
```